# Can I resume the uploading if an error occurs in firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to store my files and I am worry about unexpected situations. So if there was an error during uploading, Can I still `resume` the incomplete uploading ? or can I `pause` it and then immediately `resume` it ?

```
const task = storage.ref(`files/file1`).putFile(file);

task.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, snap => {}, err => { 

 // Is task still running ?
 // Is task stopped ?
 // Is task paused ?

 // Can still resume ?

 // what is the best thing to be done here

}, async () => {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to continue aborted/cancelled/interrupted uploads. Resuming is only possible on a task that was paused.

Comment: Thank you, so you mean if there is an error then the task gets canceled ?